# Shell syntax highlighting

Tags: syntax-highlighting, bash

I've noticed in bash/shell it highlights `$(...)` in red, for example:

[image]

However, if I change the syntax from `ft=sh` to `ft=bash`, it does not do this:

[image]

What's the reason for this? Am I doing something wrong with the `ft=sh`, or why is that highlighted in red when it's a legitimate syntax construct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because the original Bourne shell only understands `` `...` `` - the standard `$( ... )` syntax was added later. From [`syntax/sh.vim`](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/v8.2.1216/runtime/syntax/sh.vim#L304):

```
" $() and $(()): {{{1
" $(..) is not supported by sh (Bourne shell).  However, apparently
" some systems (HP?) have as their /bin/sh a (link to) Korn shell
" (ie. Posix compliant shell).  /bin/ksh should work for those
" systems too, however, so the following syntax will flag $(..) as
" an Error under /bin/sh.  By consensus of vimdev'ers!
```

You can set the variable `g:is_bash` to tell the `sh` syntax file that `sh` is actually `bash`, if indeed it is actually bash (does `sh --version` show the Bash version?). Or you can set `g:is_posix` if `sh` is POSIX compliant.

Comment: This "consensus of vimdev'ers" comment can be traced back to a Vim 7.001 commit from back in 2004, so it's been around for over 15 years, maybe even more than twenty... Looks like back in 2008 people were already asking about it and someone objected because [Solaris /bin/sh still wouldn't recognize it](http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/Syntax-highlighting-errors-for-sh-td1205735.html#a1205739). Maybe in 2020 it's time to revert that already?

Comment: Looking at [the manpage](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26502_01/html/E29030/sh-1.html#scrolltoc), that still seems to be the case for Oracle Solaris 11.1. Sigh. Maybe `g:is_posix` should be set by default and `g:is_sh` should be set only for systems with the broken sh.

Comment: Yeah... But is Solaris even relevant anymore? I thought even Oracle was mostly pushing Linux at this point...

Comment: Also, if you have such an old and quirky system... It's not like Vim syntax highlighting will add value by reminding you that you can't use `$(...)` that you didn't know yet..

Comment: I went through the discussions there and in https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=361177, and I don't know if we have a compelling argument against "backwards compatibility" there. Think it's worth posting again on vim-dev?

Comment: @muru where would I set `is_posix` ? Trying that in the shell (or in help) gives me `undefined`. Version is: `GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)`.

Comment: @David542 so macOS, where `/bin/sh` is not a symlink to `/bin/bash` but a copy or hardlink, which is why it's not guessing correctly. Put `let g:is_posix = 1` in your vimrc.

Answer (score 4):

Shell originally used only backticks for command substitution:

```
less `find . -type f`
```

But these do not nest and suffer from other problems. Bash (and probably ksh, but I’m not up on the history there) used `$()` as a newer, improved command substitution.

But that explains the difference and why the filetype matters—in fact, the shebang (`#!` line) matters! If you use `/bin/sh`, you should only use POSIX `sh` features. Otherwise, use the path to a known interpreter and use it’s features.

As pointed out in the comments, POSIX allows the newer command substitution, so it should be safe even in `sh` scripts.

Comment: `$( ... )` is perfectly fine for POSIX. (See, e.g, even [the older versions of the standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_03).)

Comment: How should I fix this then? Should I set an autocommand that if ft=`sh` set ft=bash ?

Comment: @David542 try `:let g:is_bash = 1` in your vimrc—`:help ft-sh-syntax`